# How change datetime formate in generated table by datatable.js?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, datatable, date-formatting

[image]

I have displayed a datatable using `datatable.js` . it shows datetime field shown as in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` , but i want to change this generate time format to `dd-mm-yyyy`

Comment: It is not dataTables that generates the above output, but *you* the programmer that feed dataTables with strings in that format.  It looks like a dbms date field passed from the server as a timestamp field.  The best way is to pass correct values to dataTables; the second best way is to set dataTables to modify the content on the client.

Comment: date is table is in form of YYYY-MM-DD  but datatable.js prints the timestamp by appending HH:MM:SS to it.I dont know why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can format how the date is rendered in DataTable by using `render` option. In `render` you can define your custom way to display the date, or use `Date.toLocaleDateString` method to format it. MDN reference:  [Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

```js
var payload = [{ date: new Date() }];

var table = $('#table').DataTable({

    data: payload,

    columns: [{ data: 'date', title: 'Date' }],

    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": 0,    // column index, 0 is the first column
        "type" : "date",
        "render": function (data) {
            // US English uses month-day-year order
            var date = new Date(data);
            return date.toLocaleDateString('en-US'); // 4/25/2018
        }
    }]
});
```